# ANGULAR: 'Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, pipe

Tengo un string en forma de hora que obtengo de un objeto, el cual formateo con datePipe para mostrarlo de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando presiono algunas de las horas que es cuando estoy llamando al evento clic, esto me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es que al usuario se le muestra 12:00 PM pero por detrás hay que convertirlo al tipo dateTime "2017-12-14T16:34:10" ya que de esa forma es que se debe enviar al servidor.

Este es el HTML donde recorro el objeto para la hora y darle formato:

```html
<swiper class="TimeContainer" [config]='swiperConfig' (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()">
  <ng-template swiperSlide class="SwiperItem text-center" *ngFor="let slot of slots; let i = index">

    <button *ngIf="selectedTime == slot.start" mat-stroked-button>{{slot.start | date: 'shortTime'}}
                                                </button>
    <button *ngIf="selectedTime != slot.start" mat-flat-button color='primary' class="SelectedTime" (click)="setTime(slot.start)" [disabled]="!slot.available || getHoursPased(slot.start)">{{slot.start | date: 'shortTime'}}
                                                </button>

  </ng-template>
</swiper>
```

```
  //Evento click que se llama cuando se selecciona una hora
  setTime(start: any) {
    this.selectedTime = start;
    console.log('select time', start);
    this.convertToDatetime();
  }

  convertToDatetime() {
   
    var formattedDate = this.selectedDate?.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
    var dt: Date = new Date(formattedDate + " " + this.selectedTime);
    this.bookingService.bookingModel.appointmentDate = dt;
    //let myDate = new Date();
  }
```

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de convertir "7:00 AM" a 2021-12-27T07:00:00?

Porfavor si alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: En la función `setTime(start: any)`, el parámetro `start` qué es lo que contiene? Solo la hora o la fecha completa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solucion puede ser usar la libreria moment da mejor posibilidad del manejo de fechas y permite las converciones que solicitas sin error con el pipe del templete

```js
StackMoment!:string
  stacktConvert!:string;
  stack!:string;
  stackDateString!:string;
  stackDate!:Date;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTime();
 }

  getTime(){
  // //import * as moment from 'moment';
  // para convertir usar moment permite pipe en el templete sin error de los datos requeridos
  // stacktConvert:{{stacktConvert |date:'shortTime'}}muestra stacktConvert:5:30 PM
  this.stack=' Thu Jul 26 2018 15:30:00 GMT-0500 ';
  this.StackMoment=new Date(this.stack).toISOString();
  console.log('StackMoment',this.StackMoment)
  this.stacktConvert=moment( this.StackMoment).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm")
console.log('stacktConvert',this.stacktConvert)
}
```

```html
stacktConvert:{{stacktConvert |date:'shortTime'}}
```

HTML

```html
stacktConvert:{{stacktConvert |date:'shortTime'}}
```

Comment: Gracias! La lib moment me ayudo para realizar la conversión

Comment: Si es de mucha utilidad esa librería saludos

Answer (score 1):

Las [asingaciones de fechas validas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#ejemplo_diversas_maneras_de_asignar_fechas) son las siguientes:

```
hoy = new Date();
cumpleanos = new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");
cumpleanos = new Date(1995,11,17);
cumpleanos = new Date(1995,11,17,3,24,0);
```

Para lograr lo que quieres debes de hacerlo por tu cuenta construyendo la hora. Esta es una opción:

```js
let fechaSeleccionada = "12:00 PM"
let periodo_es_pm = fechaSeleccionada.includes('PM')


let hoy = new Date()
let hora = fechaSeleccionada.split(':')[0]*1
hora = periodo_es_pm && hora > 12 ? hora+12:hora
let minutos = fechaSeleccionada.split(':')[1].split(' ')[0]*1


hoy.setHours(hora)
hoy.setMinutes(minutos)
hoy.setSeconds(0)
hoy.setMilliseconds(0)

console.log(hoy)
```